# Why use retained fragment for keeping state through configuration changes?

Tags: java, android, fragment, lifecycle

I read a lot about activity and fragment lifecycles, configuration changes and how to keep state across those.

From the information I gathered it seems like [google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) officially recommends retained fragments to keep state, even if the data that has to be kept comes from e.g an activity.

I am wondering, why this approach would be better than e.g keeping the state in a singleton that is managed centrally by the application? 
From what I understand there cannot be any fragment / activity without an application, so why not use this?

I know that singletons are frowned upon, but it seems to me like this would be a good solution for the problem, without creating (and misusing?) invisible fragments just to keep state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why this approach would be better than e.g keeping the state in a singleton that is managed centrally by the application?

A singleton is OK for app-wide state. However, there can be zero, one, or several instances of particular `Activity` subclass, making the singleton approach problematic. Plus, on the whole, we try not to have any more singletons than necessary, due to their propensity for contributing to memory leaks.

The reason for the adjective "retained" is that a retained fragment is based upon the old `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, which was a way of passing an arbitrary object from the old to the new activity on a configuration change. Retained fragments help enforce better coding practices around that "retained instance" construct.

Really, where possible, your state should go in the saved instance state `Bundle`, as that not only helps with configuration changes, but also if the user returns to your task after your process had been terminated due to low memory conditions.

Comment: I didn't even consider there to be more than one instance of an activity / fragment, this makes absolute sense.
I don't think it's possible to use the Bundle since I want to persist my REST requests etc so that they can be reused after activity restart.
Thanks for your help!